# I am creating objects with var because I mutate them but I get warning: "Variable 'variableName' was never mutated, consider..."

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am creating at launch `Dictionaries` with **`var`** because I will modify them later when user does something. `Dictionaries` are added inside an `Array` in a **singleton class** to be used in multiple places but I get the warning ***"Variable 'variableName' was never mutated, consider...."***
 in the place I am creating them

If I make them with `let` and when I get object form array to modify it if I take it from array with `var`, no crash, no warning, no nothing...

What is the explanation for this?

> UPDATE:

My Singleton Class:

```
class Config {
static let sharedInstance = Config()

var array_shapes: Array<Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>> = Array()

func createInitialShapeArray(){
    var avion = createShapeDictionaryFor("Avion", objectName: "Avion", badgeStatus: "0", shapeImageName: "shape_avion");

//.......more objects like avion

        array_shapes = [avion,//.....the other objects];



    }

    func createShapeDictionaryFor(objectID:String, objectName:String, badgeStatus:String, shapeImageName:String) -> Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>{
    var dict: Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject> = [:]
    dict["objectID"] = objectID
    dict["objectName"] = objectName
    dict["badgeStatus"] = badgeStatus
    dict["shapeImageName"] = shapeImageName

    return dict;
}

}
```

And when I am mutating dictionaries (In main class):

```
    @IBAction func btnPressed_done(sender:UIButton){

    pennyPincherGestureRecognizer.recognize();
    screenShotMethod()

    var dict = Config.sharedInstance.array_shapes[Config.sharedInstance.currentShapeIndex] as Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>
    dict["badgeStatus"] = "1"


    self.initNextShape()

}
```

**`var avion`** has the warning "Variable 'variableName' was never mutated, consider...."

It is not an error trough, it's a warning and I was curious if I could silence them or what can I do to make them dissappear

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Updated question with code

Comment: I need to see the full code of the class where `avion` is declared. Right now I don't see any code mutating `avion`. Please don't include code from other classes.

Comment: The array containing objects, has lots of objects, added only one because i thing it is enough. I wrote **And when I am mutating them:**. There I am mutating my dictionary, like "avion" when it becomes current object

Comment: Please show me the full code of the source file where the error is happening.

Comment: Updated again my question for more specific code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Facts

1. You are declaring `avion` as a local variable of the method `createInitialShapeArray`
2. You are not mutating `avion` in the scope where it is defined
3. `avion` is a `Dictionary` therefore a `Struct` (value type rules are applied)

### Conclusion

There is no need to declare `avion` as a variable, it should be a constant.

Please note that where you write

```
array_shapes = [avion, ...]
```

you are creating a copy of `avion` (because it's a Dictionary).

So if you change the value inside `array_shapes` you are changing **another value**.

Therefore, at the end of the day, **you are not mutating** `avion`... and the compiler is right, it should be a constant.

### Example

Please consider the following code

```
func foo() {
    var dict = [1: "One"] // <-- Compiler warning
    var anotherDict = dict
    anotherDict[2] = "Two"
}
```

Here I am getting the same compiler warning

> Variable 'dict' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

This happens because I am changing `anotherDict` that **is not just another reference to the same value**, it is actually **a totally different value**. This is the rule with `Struct(s)` and `Enum(s)` because they are `Value Types`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I understand now

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift arrays and dictionaries are declared as `struct` so when you pass them to other function or use them in assignments their value is copied and not passed as reference the same way it's done for classes, this means that when you pass `avion` to the `append()` function of your array you pass a copy of the dictionary so the original variable is never mutated.

The same things happens when you try to modify on dictionary in the array thus copying the dictionary of your interest in `dict`: you aren't modifying the array inside your shared instance but the local variable `dict`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, from both answers I understand what my problem was